# Java - How to print String x times as per ints in array

Tags: java, arrays, string, lambda, char

I got something like:

```
int[] array = {5, 1, 3, 4, 2};
```

..which I should turn into, e.g. for `"*"`:

```
*****
*
***
****
**
```

Simplest solutions I got so far look like:

```
// Java 8
for (int i : array) {
    System.out.println(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(i, "*")));
}

// Java 11
for (int i : array) {
    System.out.println("*".repeat(i));
}
```

Better ones with no `for` loop?

Comment: "if it ain't broke, don't fix it"...

Comment: Use following :  new string('*', 5);

Comment: @l'L'l I would rather improve it, yes. As per nature of SO. Helps learning also.

Comment: This was an excellent question, even if some people don't understand it.

Answer (score 4):

You *could* stream the array, and map each length `i` using `Collectors.joining()` and then a `forEach` to `print`. Like,

```
Arrays.stream(array).mapToObj(i -> Collections.nCopies(i, "*").stream()
        .collect(Collectors.joining())).forEach(System.out::println);
```

And if you were using Java 11+ it could be simplified further by using [`String.repeat(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int))

```
Arrays.stream(array).mapToObj(i -> "*".repeat(i)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

You *might* want something that doesn't use `Collections` like that if you're on versions less than 11, in which case a `char[]` is probably a more efficient way to construct the repeated sequence. Like,

```
Arrays.stream(array).mapToObj(i -> {
    char[] arr = new char[i];
    Arrays.fill(arr, '*');
    return new String(arr);
}).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: The JDK 11 version can use `.mapToObj("*"::repeat)`